# Mongodb/mongoose only saving once then creating 500 error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm sending json to my node.js/express app and it receives the data sent
and does what I want it to do, but only once.

the first time after I start the appjs it 200's the request and saves the data to my mongodb. I can see the data in the database and on the console log. But upon any subsequent POST's I get a 500.

This is the code for that route

```js
var express = require('express');
var phone = require('../models/phonedata-api');
var router = express.Router();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
router.use(bodyParser.json()); // support json encoded bodies
router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // support encoded bodies

router.post('/api/phone-data', function(req, res) {

 phone = new phone();
 phone.loc = req.body.loc;
 phone.battery = req.body.battery;
 phone.signal = req.body.signal;
 phone.phonedate = req.body.phonedate;
 phone.day_of_month = req.body.dom;
 phone.save(function(err) {
 if(err) 
  res.send(err); 
  })

    res.send('Phone data recived successfully');
    console.log(req.body);
});

module.exports = router;
```

And my model/schema for the database.

```js
// /models/phonedata-api.js

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var phoneSchema = new Schema({
  loc: String,
  battery:    String,
  signal: String,
  phonedate: String,
  day_of_month: String,
  date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
});

var phone = mongoose.model('phone', phoneSchema);

module.exports = phone;
```

```
{ "battery": "72",
  "signal": "-12",
  "phonedate": "09-08-2015",
  "dom": "9",
  "loc": "52.05351615,1.12653186" }
```

And my console log is.

```
> pukkapi@1.2.0 start /home/pi/Dev_work/pukkapi
> node ./bin/www

{ battery: '72',
  signal: '-1',
  phonedate: '09-08-2015',
  dom: '9',
  loc: '52.05351615,1.12653186' }
POST /admin/api/phone-data 200 29.914 ms - 31
POST /admin/api/phone-data 500 595.693 ms - 4723
```

What am I doing wrong here, am I missing pleasee something like closing the previous connection? Any pointers whats so ever will be appreciated.

Many thanks.

Comment: What are you gutting on your console also provide you sample request for rest client

Comment: your app log, you should see the error in the logs

Comment: I'm not logging to a file, just the console

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the following line:

```
phone = new phone();
```

You're importing the module `../models/phonedata-api` and assigning it to a new variable `phone` at the top of the file, then you're using that class to create an instance and assigning it back to the same variable. So, the next time the route is called the variable `phone` is no longer a function, it's an instance of an object. Try creating a new variable within the route, instead of reusing `phone`.

Answer (score 0):

Would try something like

```
new phone(req.body).save(function(err) {...
```

to avoid that `var phone` becomes assigned with a new value

Answer (score 0):

Okay,
So I agree with above two comments, here's what you can do to solve your issue.

- First thing: Don't reassign any variable. Use another variable name. Use  **const**.
- Also, you are creating new instance of schema first and then assigning them values instead you can send the object as parameter to the schema constructor so that it will generate the schema instance with your values.

  const express = require('express');
  const phone = require('../models/phonedata-api');
  const router = express.Router();
  const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
  router.use(bodyParser.json()); // support json encoded bodies
  router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // support encoded bodies

  router.post('/api/phone-data', function(req, res) {

  ```
   let data = {
      loc:req.body.loc,
      battery:req.body.battery, signal:req.body.signal, 
      phonedate:req.body.phonedate,
      day_of_month: dom
      }


  var phoneItem = new phone(data);

  phoneItem .save(function(err) {
  if(err) 
      res.send(err); 
      })

  res.send('Phone data recived successfully');
  console.log(req.body);
  });

  module.exports = router;
  ```

Hope this solves your problem.